# Mongoose: Get which condition failed in a 'find' query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to find which conditions failed in a `find` query.

Consider the following schema:

```
{
    a: String,
    b:[{
        b_id: String
      }]
}
```

I am searching for a record which matches 'a' and a 'b_id'. But if 'a' does not match then I have a different action to take and if 'b_id' is not found, then a different action.

Right now I am looking for a document with 'a' and then looping through the result to match for 'b_id'. This is not a efficient solution for me since the loop can easily go over tens of thousand times.

Is there a way to find out which condition failed to match or any other efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If you have  'a' **and** a 'b_id' condition, you retrieve only documents where both conditions are met. If you need documents with either condition, you need to use **or** query.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo you have the `collection.find().explain()` function which you can run, it will explain all the plans and how it builted the query, in which order and other useful info.